# PhoneGap jQuery JSONP returned error

Tags: jquery, cordova, jsonp

I got problem with parsing data. I send ajax request and as I can see, I get data back. But insted of going to success function, script runs error function, so something must be wrong.

```
$.ajax("http://www.test.com/something/request", {
    crossDomain:true, 
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success:function(data){
                alert("Working");
        data = evalJSON(data);
    }, error: function() { alert("Error"); }
});
```

Json data:

```
[1,{"Id":"1","Url":"my-url","Name":"Name"}]
```

Comment: Could you add your callback function please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
$.getJSON("http://www.test.com/something/request?callback=?", {
    success:function(data){
                alert("Working");
        data = evalJSON(data);
    }, error: function() { alert("Error"); }
});
```

And return the JSON data with the callback function wrapped around it. In PHP that would be like this:

```
echo $_GET['callback'] . '(' . '[1,{"Id":"1","Url":"my-url","Name":"Name"}]' . ')';
```

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out.. :)